# How to get the request.body value in asp classic?

Tags: asp-classic

In an .asp classic page I´m getting a POST send to me(a JSON string) and it is send in the `request.body`, says the guy how send it. 
But if I just have `theresponse=request.form` I am not getting anything?

So how do I get the value from a `request.body`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some payment gateway API's I've used in the past have sent responses in this fashion. The data (JSON) is sent as a binary body post.

To read it you need to use `Request.BinaryRead` with `Request.TotalBytes`, then use `Adodb.Stream` to convert the binary to UTF8 text:

```vbs
Response.ContentType = "application/json"

Function BytesToStr(bytes)
    Dim Stream
    Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Stream.Open
        Stream.Write bytes
        Stream.Position = 0
        Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
        Stream.Charset = "utf-8"
        BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
        Stream.Close
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Function

' You shouldn't really be receiving any posts more than a few KB,
' but it might be wise to include a limit (200KB in this example),
' Anything larger than that is a bit suspicious. If you're dealing
' with a payment gateway the usual protocol is to post the JSON 
' back to them for verification before processing. 

if Request.TotalBytes > 0 AND Request.TotalBytes <= 200000 then

    Dim postBody
    postBody = BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes))

    Response.Write(postBody) ' the JSON... hopefully 

end if
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT Adam :-) It is getting the JSON now. But it says that I can´t use Request.Form after BinaryRead. This is a webhook url and I would like to send some variables with it that I receive along with the JSON data, is that possible?

Comment: So they are sending the JSON to my web hook url, and I would like to do this with that url, https://mydomain.se/getorderinfo.asp?personal_id=1234ordernummer=789. So how can I get those values if I can´t use request.form after BinaryRead?

Comment: I'm not too sure what it is you're wanting to do, but `Request.Form` is used to retrieve form data, not set it. If you're wanting to post back to the webhook sender you would need to use a method such as `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` to create and send a `POST` body back. You can include your variables in the post body, here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302015/4901783

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the JSON is being posted to: `mydomain.se/getorderinfo.asp?personal_id=1234&ordernummer=789` and you want to retrieve the `personal_id` and `ordernumber` values aswell as the JSON? If so you would need to use `request.querystring` rather than `request.form`.

Comment: Yes the JSON is getting posted to the url in my webhook mydomain.se/getorderinfo.asp?personal_id=1234&ordernummer=789 Ok, good, I will test it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: GOOD! It worked! I get the personal_id variable. When I receive an ordinary payment, I get a paymentFailed if the transaction failed, do you think that I will get the same with a web hook? Or are they not sending anything to a webhook if a transaction fails?

Comment: A payment gateway API should send transaction details of any kind to your webhook, not just successful transaction data.

Comment: Ok, good. Ok so I have manage to get it working if I send a valid JSON from this test page: https://reqbin.com and it inserts it to my database. And I´m using aspJSON.asp to handle the JSON string. But when I make a payment I can see that it is sending to my web hook url, but I can´t get the value from the JSON string. Do you have any idea why I can POSt a test JSON to the page and I can get the values from that JSON string, but not when I get it from the web hook?

Comment: This is what I got just to see if it works. jsonstring = Cstr(postBody)      
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON
        oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)
 theevent=oJSON.data("Event")
 sql= "INSERT INTO ordrar(artikel) VALUES ('"&theevent&"');"
     conn.Execute (sql)